# relation between QEventloop and QAbstractEventDispatcher

Tags: qt4

What is the relation between `QEventloop` and `QAbstractEventDispatcher` ?

> Event loop is a loop that runs the event dispatcher until the loop is broken.

But in Documentation of `QEventLoop` there is no single method that takes an `QAbstractEventDispatcher`  as argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should there be a method in QEventLoop that takes a Subclass of `QAbstractEventDispatcher`?

In every application, or more precise in every thread there is **only one** `QAbstractEventDispatcher` subclass instance which is only processing incomint system/Qt events and dispatches them to the `Q(Core)Application`. The `QAbstractEventDispatcher` is only a helper, it isn't listening to events, it has to be triggered, for example by a `QEventLoop`. The Eventloop is basically a infinite loop which uses the thread global event dispatcher to dispatch events if need be.
I hope that clears it up a little.

Comment: So `Q(Core)Application` inherits `QAbstractEventDispatcher`

Comment: No, `QCoreApplication` inherits `QObject`. But it does utilize a subclass of it, on a Windows system the `QEventDispatcherWin32` for example. The `QAbstractEventDispatcher` is just a helping class, but there is allways only one object of it present per thread. The `QEventLoop` just polls it in a loop.